# How to get the initial file path in Tauri

Tags: tauri

I'm trying to make a [Tauri](https://tauri.app/) application. In electron there is the `app.on("open-file",` event and the `app.on("ready",` event that allow you to get the file that was opened **and** started your application (note this is different than opening a file from a dialog once the app is already open).

What's the equivalent way to do this in Tauri?

Let me know if you need additional information.
Thanks very much

Answer (score 2):

I might be misunderstanding the question since I'm not familiar with electron, but you should be able to get the file path using [Tauri's dialog functions](https://tauri.app/v1/api/js/dialog/). With the open dialog, you should be able to prompt the user to select a file, have them select it in the file dialog and store that filepath as a result of the action.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I updated my issue to be more specific. I'm looking for the file that was double clicked that caused the application to be launched in the first place, not a file that is opened from a dialog once the app is already running. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

According to someone on the tauri discord, this feature does not yet exist but it is being worked on - "Tauri doesn't have that feature yet. It's being worked on by a community member tho."

Welp I guess I'll be waiting until that feature is implemented.

Answer (score 0):

Also from the discord chat:

> For now, you can work around this limitation by getting the file from the args() or args_os() from std::env in Rust and use a #[tauri::command] function to invoke it from your JavaScript. Note that args() will panic if invalid UTF-8 is provided so it might be more stable to use args_os() instead, which would allow you to handle unexpected input gracefully.

I'll have to play around with this to verify it works.